# JNI method object called on creation

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

Using JNI I am storing a reference to a Java method object (`obj`) in order to call it later from C:

```
 jobject obj = (*newEnv)->NewObject(newEnv, cls, mid);
```

where `newEnv` is my environment, `cls` is my class ID and `mid` is my method ID.

Everything works fine except that upon creating this object to be used as a reference later, it actually calls the method right away.

I would like to just create the object for later and not call the method immediately.

Comment: This code doesn't store a method object, this creates a new class.  So yes, the constructor will be called immediately.  You can save the method id of a constructor by finding the <init> method.  But creating the object will create it immediately.

Comment: The mid in NewObject should be the mid of the construtor of the object, not of some method on the object.  If you're passing any method other than the constructor there, you're doing it wrong.  And if you want to call a constructor via CallVoidMethod, you're also doing it wrong-  a constructor cannot be called as a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gabe Sechan's comments I was able to figure it out:

```
jmethodID construct = (*newEnv)->GetMethodID(newEnv,cls,"<init>","()V");
jobject obj = (*newEnv)->NewObject(newEnv, cls, construct);
```

Then I can call the method I want using:

```
(*newEnv)->CallVoidMethod(newEnv, obj, mid);
```